# compactness in $\Bbb R^2$ of $\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $ \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2+y^2>1\} $

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**

$Y= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$
 and $R^2$ equipped with the euclidean metric

$W= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2>1\} $ and $R^2$  equipped with the euclidean metric

is Y compact in $R^2$?

is W compact in $R^2$?

---

**Thms, Def**

A subset of a metric space is compact $\iff $ sequentially compact

sequentialy compact $\iff $ complete and bounded

A subset K of metric space X is compact

if evry open cover of K  has a finite subcover

---

**Attempt**

Y is bounded. Y should be closed since it only maps to 1.

W is not closed since

$$x_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$$ $\forall n \in N$ $x_n\in W$ but $lim_{n\to \infty } x_n \not \in W$ $\therefore W $ is not closed $\Rightarrow$  W is not compact

**have trouble making argument by showing W is not compact by open covers**

Comment: 3rd line after the word "Problem". is $X=\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: is a typo, fixed

Comment: @Ugo , do you think that $W$ is bounded?

Comment: @Theportakal i saw $1<x^2+y^2$. anyways, So W is not bounded then not compact

Comment: "have trouble making argument by showing W is not compact by open covers"  I can help you with that ({x^2 + y^2 > 1/n} is an open cover with no finite subcover), but why do you need to?  You just showed W isn't compact as it isn't closed?  Why do you *also* need to show it be lack of finite subcovers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Heine–Borel theorem, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. Thus, $Y$ is compact (it is both closed and bounded), whereas $W$ is not compact (it is not bounded).